# MDX: how to union results from two dimensions?

Tags: mdx

I'm new to MDX. Now I want to combine two results from 2 different dimensions. I'm using codes as following:

```
With 
 MEMBER [Measures].[Student Head Count].[Program1] AS
([Program1].[Program1].&[1])
MEMBER [Measures].[Student Head Count].[Program2] AS
([Program2].[Program2].&[1]) 

SELECT
NON EMPTY
{
[Measures].[Student Head Count].[Program1] ,
[Measures].[Student Head Count].[Program2]
}
ON COLUMNS

FROM [Current Student Overview]
```

The error shows:

```
The Program1 calculated member cannot be created because its parent is at the lowest level in the Measures hierarchy.
```

I know that “Student Head Count" is at the lowest level, but I don't know how to modify the syntax. If I replace “Student Head Count"  with "Test" , it's not working either. Also, "Union" does not work as I tried. Could anyone help me with modified or new MDX?

I tried with Crossjoin with following script:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY
{

 [Measures].[Student Head Count]
}
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{
NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN({[Program1].[Program1].&[1]},{[Program2].[Program2] }),
NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN({[Program1].[Program1] },{[Program2].[Program2].&[1]})  
}
on 1


FROM [Current Student Overview]
```

THe result is:

[image]

How could I eliminate or hide the "All" column in performancepoint then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one level on the Measure dimension. Your measure name should be be `[Measures].[Program21]` and `[Measures].[Program2]`.

You can also rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY
{
    ([Program1].[Program1].&[1], [Program2].[Program2].&[1])
}
ON COLUMNS
FROM [Current Student Overview]
WHERE ([Measures].[Student Head Count])
```

In Mdx you cannot union results from different dimensions but you can do the cross product with the [CrossJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144816) function.

EDIT:
You do not need to use CrossJoin when you have only one member in your sets. You can do `(member1, member2)`.

If you do not want to see `All` you can use a query like this one:

```
WITH
 MEMBER [Measures].[Student Head Count Program1] AS
    ([Measures].[Student Head Count], [Program1].[Program1].&[1], [Program2].[Program2].[All])
MEMBER [Measures].[Student Head Count Program2] AS
    ([Measures].[Student Head Count], [Program1].[Program1].[All], [Program2].[Program2].&[1]) 
SELECT
NON EMPTY
{
    [Measures].[Student Head Count Program1] ,
    [Measures].[Student Head Count Program2]
}
ON COLUMNS
FROM [Current Student Overview]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! However, there will be errors since these two are different dimensions. I'm trying crossjoin now but the result shows as the snapshot in my edited question. How could I hide the "All" column for presenting?